# 502 Bad Gateway when my second instance of api tries to connect to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

So I have two expressjs apis on two different ec2 instances running ubuntu distros on node 16.

There is a load balancer and when I hit my-service-mywebsite.com/verify, the first api instance run successfully, but the second one gives me an error. In the browser the error is 502 bad gateway, but in terminal the error is: `getServiceConfig: Unable to get config from S3! Error [CredentialError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AwS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

It's the same exact api, or it should be, not sure why one hits the s3 bucket successfully and the second one does not. Does AWS S3 have an issue with being hit twice in a round-robin style?

As a result I only have one running instance with the api in production, I cannot figure out why the second one gives me the above error.

Comment: Both instances have same roles attached to them?

Comment: has enough time elapsed for the roles to be propagated to all the instances?

Comment: @user3783243, that's exactly what it was, I had assigned the IAM role to one and not the other.